# How to do dynamic regex matching, in redshift?

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

So, I have a table with one of columns(say A) a "string", and another column having the corresponding "regex pattern", is it possible to check if the regex matches string value in column A for every column in the table dynamically? If not, is there any other tool which I can integrate with redshift to do dynamic regex matching?

Comment: `select * from table where column_a ~ column_with_regex`? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Comment: I tried this way before, it throws up this error 
`The pattern must be a valid UTF-8 literal character expression`
The above way only works incase I give a string literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I found a work around for this, turns out there is no way you can do a dynamic regex matching in redshift, but you can achieve this using python UDF, one of the features aws redshift cluster provides.

Comment: It is a confirmation. Yes. The one you are sugessting is matching a column with a static regex. The question states the matching has to be done in a dynamic way with the regex to be used also a value in a table. So, yes this is a workaround.

Comment: You can use a Python UDF, yes, but they are incredibly slow at scale, at least in our use case.   Have you not found that to be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION regex_match(input_str character varying, in_pattern character varying)
RETURNS character varying AS
'import re
if re.match(in_pattern,input_str):
       a=input_str
else:
       a ="False"
return(a)
End'
LANGUAGE plpythonu STABLE;
```

Once we create above function, below query does a regex match on columns from two different tables and returns matched strings where one table has strings and other table has patterns.

```
select distinct regex_match from 
(select  regex_match(t1.col1,t2.col2) as regex_match
from t1, t2)
where regex_match<>'False'
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the variable column `variable` and you want to achieve the regex `'.*variable.*'` you could split your regex into two and then concatenate the splitted parts with your variable like:

```
'.*' + variable + '.*'
```

I know this is a bit hacky but it maybe less effort than going into the UDF approach.

**EDIT:**
Actually this works only when typing the pattern in a WITH clause, not when you pull the data from a table, so this solution doesn't work.